# Qt get path to application for file type

Tags: qt, file

I want to use open parameters for a file but QDesktopServices doesn't work that way so I'll be using QProcess but for that I need to have the path to the application. I've used QFileIconProvider to get the icon and QFileInfo to get the type but how can I get the path to the application that the OS will use for the desired file?

I would like to have a filename, get the application path, depending on the application (different open parameter syntax given the application) use the application path with the filename and the open file parameters

Answer (score 0):

**QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();**

Returns the directory that contains the application executable.

For example, if you have installed Qt in the C:\Qt directory, and you run the regexp example, this function will return "C:/Qt/examples/tools/regexp".

Comment: I don't need this for my program, but when using my program, a user selects a file, I need to determine which application to use to open that file. e.g. if a user selects a video file, I need to get the path to the video player to use open parameters with it.